# Can I connect one firebase web app with 2 react.js applications one for user panel and one for admin panel

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I using the same configuration for both projects one user side projects works absolutely fine but another projects have issues it configure and work but after 1 or 2 hits of api it shows me an error

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

here is the code that I use for configuration

```
const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "****",
 authDomain: "****",
 projectId: "****",
 storageBucket: "****",
 messagingSenderId: "****",
 appId: "****",
 measurementId: "****",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig,"secondary");
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

I need to connect both projects with one firebase web app

Comment: Why do you think that error message would have anything to do with your configuration?  It's saying something completely different.  Please edit the question to show all the information and instructions someone can use to reproduce the error.

Comment: In addition to what @DougStevenson suggests, to answer your primary question: yes, you can have multiple front-end programs using the same Firebase project configuration.  You can also have multiple "apps" defined in your Firebase project. [The word "app" is overloaded and a bit ambiguous in Firebase contexts].